# Meaning of "Hounds, when the huntsman tumbles, are at fault" in Byron's Don Juan

Tags: meaning, lord-byron, don-juan

From Byron's *[Don Juan](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Don_Juan_(Byron)/Canto_the_Eighth)*:

> The troops, already disembark'd, push'd on
>       To take a battery on the right; the others,
>   Who landed lower down, their landing done,
>       Had set to work as briskly as their brothers:
>   Being grenadiers, they mounted one by one,
>       Cheerful as children climb the breasts of mothers,
>   O'er the entrenchment and the palisade,
>   Quite orderly, as if upon parade.
>
> And this was admirable; for so hot
>       The fire was, that were red Vesuvius loaded,
>   Besides its lava, with all sorts of shot
>       And shells or hells, it could not more have goaded.
>   Of officers a third fell on the spot,
>       **A thing which victory by no means boded
>
>   To gentlemen engaged in the assault:
>
>   Hounds, when the huntsman tumbles, are at fault**.

So when a huntsman stumbles over something, he blames his hounds. But how does that explain that "since 33% of the officers died in the attack, this was a sign that the army was to be victorious"?

These two observations seem unrelated to me. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't agree that this is litotes, since there is no positive to be wrung from the negative constructions.

Let's parse the passage a bit more deeply. First stanza summation: **The grenadiers had landed ashore and immediately pushed their way past the defenses in an orderly fashion.**

Second stanza summation: **The actions of the grenadiers were admirable, even in the face of intense opposing fire that relentlessly cut the attackers down. But even if they had faced a volcano of fire, it could not have pushed them forward as much as the fear of failure, of being blamed for defeat.**

Now to the final four lines (you only bolded three, but four are necessary since the final sentence includes four):

> Of officers a third fell on the spot
>   A thing which victory by no means boded
>   To gentlemen engaged in the assault:

In other words, casualties were occurring at an alarming rate, which suggested to the "gentlemen" (which is a class marker, since in that era only the upper class could "buy their colors," i.e., become officers) that victory was certainly in jeopardy.

> Hounds, when the huntsman stumbles, are at fault.

If the huntsman (in this case, likely the commander of the attack) falls, it is human nature to lay the blame elsewhere. I believe the statement is merely a reflection that subordinates are all too often blamed for their leader's failures. Or, as you'll hear frequently in business and military circles, "shit flows downhill."

Comment: Thank you! It turns out I mistook "by no means boded" for "by all means boded". Sloppy reading on my part.

Answer (score 1):

This is an instance of [litotes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Litotes). (Using "understatement to emphasize a point by stating a negative to further affirm a positive, often incorporating double negatives for effect", says the mother of all knowledge.) "By no means boded" = "did not augur well" = "looked bad".  Because a third were killed, it seemed that victory was not not certain [here I'm doing it, too], that is, victory was unlikely.